# Identify table in visualization in Spotfire

Tags: python, spotfire

I am trying to identify which table the data table visualizations are referring to using a script. I don't want to rely on the name, in case someone changes it and it does not reflect the data table anymore. Is there a way to do this? I have included the code that cycles through the pages and visualizations and gets there type.

```
for d in Document.Pages:
    Document.ActivePageReference=d
        for visual in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
           print visual.TypeId
           #here I would like to print the table that is being referred to if it is data table visualization
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the data table name

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
for d in Document.Pages:
    Document.ActivePageReference=d
    for visual in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
        if visual.TypeId.Name<>'Spotfire.HtmlTextArea':
            #Spotfire.HtmlTextArea don't have data tables
            vis=visual.As[VisualContent]()
            print vis.Data.DataTableReference.Name
```